# Center domain label Androidplot bar chart

Tags: android, androidplot

Currently the domain label is positioned below the Y axis labels. Is there a way to set the domain label to appear in the middle of the X axis?

Using the below image as an example I want the domain label (Time secs) to appear where the legend (Thread #1) appears. (legend will not be visible).

[image: chart example]
<sub>(source: [androidplot.com](http://androidplot.com/wp-content/gallery/plot-examples/stepchart1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

To center the domain label I used the below.

```
plot.getDomainLabelWidget().position(0, XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_CENTER, 0, YLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_BOTTOM,  AnchorPosition.BOTTOM_MIDDLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the "LayoutManager" section](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/plot_composition.md#the-layoutmanager) of the "Plot Composition" doc. It gives a pretty good summary of how to position the visual elements (referenced as widgets in the doc) of a plot.  In your case you'll be invoking **plot.getDomainTitle().position(...)**.

Comment: Im not seeing this section in the documentation. My plot also does not have the function getDomainLabelWidget(). Can you point me to an updated place in the documentation where I can find this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with v1.5.4:

```
plot.getDomainTitle().getPositionMetrics().setXPositionMetric(new HorizontalPosition(0, HorizontalPositioning.ABSOLUTE_FROM_CENTER));
```

It sets the horizontal position to the center without modifying the vertical position.

It may also be useful to set the text alignment to CENTER:

```
plot.getDomainTitle().getLabelPaint().setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```